# Как исправить SQL запрос

Tags: sql

Я хочу получить среднее количество треков с именем "Rock" по альбомам.

```
SELECT AVG("ЧТО ЗДЕСЬ НАПИСАТЬ???" )
FROM (SELECT Count([track].name) as tab 
FROM album, track
WHERE ([track.name]="Rock" AND [album].album_id=[track].album_id)
GROUP BY [album].album_id
HAVING (Count ([track].name>1)));
```

Comment: а много вариантов у вас, что там написать, если в запросе from вы выбираете единственное поле tab ?

Comment: в having явная неразбериха со скобками, и вероятно `>=1` надо, а не строгое